# Does Flutter write on SQLite with UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Tags: flutter, sqlite

What happens when I write on a SQLite db? Does Flutter write UTF-16 strings or convert them to UTF-8?

And when I read? Does Flutter find UTF-16 strings or find UTF-8 strings and convert them back to UTF-16?

Comment: Flutter doesn't provide APIs to operate on SQLite databases.  If you're asking about a specific package that operates on SQLite databases, you need to explain which package you're using...

Comment: Flutter doesn't have a native API for SQLite. Are you referring to `sqflite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Flutter doesn't have a native SQLite API, I assume you are referring to `sqflite`.

Under the hood, `sqflite` relies on the `MethodChannel` class to communicate with the SQLite APIs. Whenever a method is invoked, a query or a command will go through the `MethodChannel` via [the native `invokeMethod`](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/30b81e87a7fef5be657d4c7194a183c40b993d78/sqflite/lib/src/sqflite_impl.dart#L15).

`invokeMethod` is called on the [`MethodChannel` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html), and `invokeMethod` essentially executes a call to SQLite using binary.

But if you look closely at the documentation and the code. Since a codec wasn't specified when [initiating the `MethodChannel`](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/30b81e87a7fef5be657d4c7194a183c40b993d78/sqflite/lib/src/sqflite_impl.dart#L9) class it will use [the `StandardMethodCodec` by default](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/StandardMethodCodec-class.html).

If you look [within the code comments](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/message_codecs.dart#L274-L276) closely, it states that a `String` will encode into a UTF-8 format. While this does not answer your question directly, you can assume that given the information available, Flutter encodes `String` to UTF-8 before sending it to SQLite and vice-versa.

I don't have definitive answers for other data types though, but guessing that it uses UTF-8 too isn't too far-fetched of a guess.